# слушатель буфера обмена

Tags: java

Возможно ли написать программу без UI , которая будет слушать изменения в буфере обмена? Например: запустил программу, далее захожу например в браузер и копирую строчку текста. Моя программа уловила, что буфер изменился и делает дальнейшие манипуляции. 
Использовать собираюсь в виндовс.
 Что то, я прочитал, что это тяжело реализовать и в фоне отлавливать изменения буфера по всей винде не получится.
 Ну и если возможно, то методы слушателя пожалуйста в студию.
Если бы мне нужен был слушатель в моей программе , то подключить его было бы не тяжело, а как подключить слушатель на буфер обмена виндовс мне не понятно.
Как вариант, отслеживать нажатие горячих клавиш ctrl+c, но это тоже, как я понял, не просто. Для отслеживания таких глобальных клавиш нашел проект [jkeymaster](https://github.com/tulskiy/jkeymaster) , но каким образом в этом проекте отлавливаются нажатия горячих клавиш вне моего приложения мне не ясно. Да и хотелось бы отлавливать изменение буфера обмена не только при копирование через горячие клавиши, но и копирование посредством мыши (выделил, клик на правую клавишу, копировать).

Comment: Для работы с виндой есть Win API, в нем есть возможность добраться практически до чего угодно в винде,

Comment: Или берите с++ и пишите нативные методы. Хотя в принципе там тоже глубже Win API не нырнете. Ну точнее смысла нет

Comment: я кроме как писать на java под андроид другого опыта не имею. Так что другие языки не рассматриваю. Сейчас подключил библиотеку jnativehook. Пытаюсь разобраться.

Comment: Да, всё получилось, jnativehook это обертка над хуками винды и слушает клавиатуру даже , если мое приложение свернуто.

Comment: Единственное, не знаю как ловить клик мыши на копирование из меню, вызываемого при нажатие правой клавиши мыши. В библиотеке я такой реализации не заметил. Возможно ли это вообще используя WIN API ?  Ну или по другому : есть ли слушатель буфера обмена, чтобы не слушать клавиатуру ожидая комбинации ctrl+c ?

Comment: нет ни у кого идей как определить изменение буфера? Просто на сайте есть кнопка, по нажатию на которую копируется текст из нее. Это чтобы не приходилось тратить время на выделение текста. И в таком случае я не знаю, как определить изменение буфера. Всё время его сверять, как то слишком не изящно кажется.